# Weighted output by comparing strings in python

Tags: python, arrays, string-comparison

I am relatively new to python and I am having problem with how to proceed in this situation. I have 5 results from 5 sources. Each source has a numerical weight. like city1 to city5 has respective weights of 2,2,1,1,2. The 5 results need to be cut down to 3 or less based on the sum of weights of each choice.

In the example's case,  for row 1 after the weights are assigned, the choices look like this

```
NewYork - 2 + 1 = 3 (city1,city4)  
Barcelona - 2 (city2)   
Lisbon - 1 (city3)
London - 2 (city5)
```

The output must be the choices with combined weights more than or equal to 2
i.e.,  NewYork, Barcelona,London.
Likewise, in row two the output should be London and NewYork

I should be able to do it with multiple rows of data.

Example:

```
City1        City2        City3        City4     City5   
NewYork     Barcelona    Lisbon       NewYork  London  
London      NewYork      Sydney       Dublin   London
```

Comment: Can you show more examples (rows of data, weighting factors, desired results)? I don't quite understand the problem yet.

Comment: Finally I've understood the question. Are the possible cities that can occur is predefined? Or I can enter an arbitary city name? I can't simply split the line because the city name **New York** will be splitted into two parts **new** and **york** .

Comment: @TimPietzcker, I have made the example more detailed.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque yes, the possible cities that can occur are predefined. But I don't think that matters here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this solution help you

```
city={}
weight=[2,2,1,1,2]


with open('example.txt','r') as f:
    lst=f.read().splitlines()
    for line in lst[1:]:
        innerList=line.split()
        for index,element in enumerate(innerList):
            if element in city:
                city[element] += weight[index]
            else:
                city[element]= weight[index]

 print city
```

Finally, to pick highest three occurances of city, do:

```
print sorted(city.iteritems(),key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)[:3]
```